# 404 when submit Forgot password form added in custom theme

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, 404

I have added a `forgot password` form to all the pages, by adding the following line in the `default.xml` of my custom theme:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword.pop" template="Magento_Customer::form/forgotpassword.phtml">
```

But, when the end-user clicks on the `Reset my password button`, the page redirects to this URL:

`/cms/index/forgotpasswordpost`

And the page returns the `404`  (screenshot is attached).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**M 2.2**

[image: nested-forgotpassword-form-404-error]

Comment: I'm having this same issue on 2.3.5 did you manage to find out what was causing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to just add a **forgetpassword** link:

   Add the code bellow in your `default.xml`

   ```
   <container name="forgetpassword-custom" label="forgetpassword link in all pages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="forgetpassword-custom-link">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="forgetpassword.custom">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Forgot Your Password ?</argument>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customer/account/forgotpassword/</argument>
               <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
           </arguments>
       </block>
   </container>
   ```
2. If you want to add completely the `forgetpassword form` then you submit it correctly **without** your 404 error

   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/forgetpassword-custom.phtml**

   ```
   <form class="form password forget"
     action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpasswordpost')) ?>"
     method="post"
     id="form-validate"
     data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
   <fieldset class="fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
       <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please enter your email address below to receive a password reset link.')) ?></div>
       <div class="field email required">
           <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
           <div class="control">
               <input type="email" name="email" alt="email" id="email_address" class="input-text" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getEmailValue()) ?>" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
           </div>
       </div>
       <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="actions-toolbar">
       <div class="primary">
           <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
       </div>
       <div class="secondary">
           <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLoginUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span></a>
       </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   ```

   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

   ```
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="forgetpassword.custom" template="Magento_Theme::html/forgetpassword-custom.phtml" />
   ```